# Why not equal function not working this realm query

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have to below simple query to filter search result form local realm data base on android application for some reason this `notEqualTo()` function not working correctly. please refer below debug screen shot.

[image]

As you can see in query result set we should not get a result which code equal "CMB" what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```
data = realm
       .where(DestinationTable.class)
       .notEqualTo("code",otherSelectedAirport)
       .beginGroup()
       .like("country", newText+"*", Case.INSENSITIVE)
       .or()
       .like("label", newText+"*", Case.INSENSITIVE)
       .endGroup()
       .findAll();
```